# Angular 5 data table pagination not work when getting data from service

Tags: angular, datatable, angular2-services, angular2-directives

installed this one
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-datatables-5

in demo they are used data from constant then it is working fine ,

```
this.filmResource.query(params).then(films => this.films = films);
```

here films is a constant

but when i call service for getting data , table populated but pagination is not work , but data populated without any issue .

```
this._productListService.getProductList().subscribe((productListData)=>{this.filmResource.query(params).then(films => this.films = productListData['deliveredOrdersSearchList'] );this.productList=productListData['deliveredOrdersSearchList'];this.spinnerService.hide(); return this.productList; });
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer change service calling and data table initialize and counter increment placed inside the method and variables initialized above method working fine

```
 DataResource;
    filmCount;
    films = [];
    this. _productListService.getProductList().subscribe(result => {
            this.films = result;
            this.filmCount = result.length;
            this.DataResource = new DataTableResource(this.films);
            this.DataResource.query(params).then(films => this.films = films);
            this.DataResource.count().then(count => this.filmCount = count);
        });
```